# How to get Users unique Id at the time of logging JasperReports Server?

Tags: jasperserver

Please tell me if there is any method through which I can get the users unique id who logged into the *JasperReports Server*, and that id could be used in the report to display only those records matching this id.

Is there any parameter which can be referred or any other work around to obtain the logged in user id or any other way to deal with the issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the username of user who logged into Jasper Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323614/how-to-get-the-username-of-user-who-logged-into-jasper-server)

Comment: [Built-in Parameters for Logged In User](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/built-parameters-logged-user)

Comment: I have set the attribute for agentuser AgentId when agentuser loggs in jasper server from where we would get his Id ,do we need to make extra AgentId field on login page.

Comment: AgentUser – access to all records but limited to those with an AgentID matching their own (custom user field called AgentID). If not set in the user profile, then this filter is not used

Comment: The question is different with the username